# How to avoid from .map file being created in ionic 2 app?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have designed an ionic 2 app. The apk size was too high, After running the ionic build with --prod. ionic app script is creating the .map file in the www folder. That file size is too high. Is there a way to avoid from .map file being created?

Comment: In angular CLI their is a --no-sourcemap parameter, I don't know if it works on Ionic though.

Answer (score 0):

In you package.json file of your project add the following configuration:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
}
"config": {
   "ionic_generate_source_map": "false",
},
```

or you can also you the cli flag `--generateSourceMap`

For more info you can check out the [doc](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts)

Comment: I have tried this.                                                                                    "config": {
   "ionic_generate_source_map": false,
}  . But still, source map file is generating.

Comment: I updated the answer to string instead of boolean - you can try it now @Dheena

Comment: Yeah I tried that also. Still, Its generating the .map file. @galvan

Answer (score 0):

So, I started my app in **Icognito Mode** with `{ "ionic_generate_source_map" : false }` then it works fine. Perhaps, the angular's cache needed to be cleared.